# Docker starting cron service, but when opening terminal it is not running anymore?

Tags: linux, docker, cron, docker-compose

I have a simple Dockerfile and docker compose setup to test cron in a container.

As a last step, cron is started and I get the message cron has started, but when I log into the container and check on the status of the cron service, it is not running. How is this possible?

I believe I am misunderstanding something but can't figure out quite what it is.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Install Cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron

# Install the crontab
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# Is this needed??
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN chmod 777 /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD service cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  cron:
    # build a custom image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    # a name for easier reference
    image: cron
```

The file `crontab` is valid and contains:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required.
```

Then starting it with: `docker-compose up --build`
The output is:

```
Creating network "docker-cron_default" with the default driver
Building cron
Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu:bionic
 ---> 4c108a37151f
Step 2/8 : MAINTAINER wouter.samaey@storefront.be
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0d9fa7049481
Step 3/8 : RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 39bb838fe945
Step 4/8 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d3ce6cc03821
Step 5/8 : COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fab99f2e2e77
Step 6/8 : RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c7fab49def98
Step 7/8 : RUN chmod 777 /var/log/cron.log
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7dc00a5913bd
Step 8/8 : CMD service cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
 ---> Running in a4bdec436613
Removing intermediate container a4bdec436613
 ---> 97c867e25091
Successfully built 97c867e25091
Successfully tagged cron:latest
Creating docker-cron_cron_1 ... done
Attaching to docker-cron_cron_1
cron_1  |  * Starting periodic command scheduler cron
cron_1  |    ...done.
```

But when I open the bash shell on this container, cron is NOT running:

```
docker run -it cron /bin/bash

root@d6649b402133:/# /etc/init.d/cron status
 * cron is not running
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What does `ps aux` give you inside the container? I wonder if the command you are issuing is just for services, but Cron is not running as a service.

Comment: `ps aux` only shows 2 lines. No cron. Very strange why there are only 2 lines...

Answer (score 2):

A Docker container runs only one process.  When you

```
docker run --rm -it imagename bash
```

the shell runs *instead of* the `CMD` in the Dockerfile.

Typical best practice is to run the thing you want to run as a foreground process.  In your example, if there's some sort of bug that causes crond to crash, you'd never notice, since your container's main process is "sleep forever".  Correspondingly, getting interactive shells in containers like you show is really useful for debugging ("if my file isn't in `/etc/cron.d` then where is it actually?") but it isn't a really standard way to operate Docker.

In short: I'd change the last line of your Dockerfile to

```
CMD ["crond", "-n"]
```

to cause the daemon to start as a foreground process, and not worry about trying to get a shell at the same time.

Comment: Good spot David! Wouter, if you swap to `docker exec` then you should see your Cron process running.

Comment: ^ You will need to `docker run <image> -d` to start with, in order to start it as a container, and put it in the background.

Comment: How can I run this with `docker-compose` (I want to setup a more complex set of containers so sticking to `docker-compose`). Currently, I cannot see if cron is running or not, because I can't see the contents of `/var/log/cron.log` with cron running in the foreground. Any way around this? Also for Ubuntu, the command is `cron -f`, but that's fine.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/crond seems to document Vixie cron (which is where `-n` came from).

Comment: Since the `CMD` modification causes `crond` to be the main container process, there's no ambiguity: if the container is running, then cron is running.  You can also mount a volume on to `/var/log` in the container so that log files are readable from the host.

Comment: Ok, so now if I want to have cron do something for my main application, I create a separate container and mount the same volume as the main application. So this way I have 1 volume for both Apache/PHP and cron containers. Putting cron inside the Apache/PHP container would be bad practise? Sharing the volume is fine I guess?